# Python from within Python

Tags: python, subprocess

I'm trying to launch a simple server from a Python script:

```
    server = Popen(['python' ,'-m', 'SimpleHTTPServer', '9090'], stderr=STDOUT, stdout=PIPE)
    output = server.communicate()[0]  # <- DEBUG
```

Reading the output, I see:

```
'/usr/bin/python: Import by filename is not supported.'
```

What's the problem? How to solve it?

Comment: Works fine for me. Make it log to the screen directly. Let's see what it says. Also, don't import Popen and the rest of `subprocess` into your current namespace.

Comment: can't log to the screen as it is withing a library and it's not a console application.

Comment: I tested your code on windows and it works fine.

Comment: I suspect that your library is messing up then rather than the subprocess call. That works fine from a regular Python shell.

Comment: +1 to Noufal - my guess is that it's environmental - the "python" being invoked by Popen ('/usr/bin/python' based on the output) might be a different version, but one of the PYTHON...PATH environment variables might be pointing somewhere else...

Comment: Try `sys.executable` instead of `'python'`.

Comment: I've got the same problem in PyCharm/Linux (with the same `SimpleHTTPServer`). I believe all my environment variables are set right to my virtualenv, and I'm using `sys.executable`. A bit stuck here.

Answer (score 1):

I suggest change to code to this:

```
import SimpleHTTPServer
import SocketServer

PORT = 9090

Handler = SimpleHTTPServer.SimpleHTTPRequestHandler

httpd = SocketServer.TCPServer(("", PORT), Handler)

print "serving at port", PORT
httpd.serve_forever()
```

Comment: This has the decided disadvantage that the script cannot perform other tasks while the server runs in the background.